# Escape brackets in input

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a quick script to pass simple calculations through to bc, however when I try a calculation involving brackets I get the following error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

How do I write the script to escape any characters given to it?

This is the code I have now:

```
calc()
{
    echo "$*" | bc
}
```

And I call it with things like:

```
calc 100 + 10 + (10 * 10)
```

Quoting the input works but I'd like to not have to (I'm clearly lazy enough to be trying to make adding numbers easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
calc '100 + 10 + (10 * 10)'
calc 100 + 10 + '(10 * 10)'
calc 100 + 10 + \(10 \* 10\)
```

The error is not in `calc()` but in the code calling it. Parentheses and asterisks are special characters in the shell so you need to quote them. There's nothing you can do within `calc()` since the shell's barfing before it even calls it.

> Quoting the input works but I'd like to not have to.

It's unavoidable. Sorry!